# Can not get TextInputLayout & TextInputEditText to style correctly on disabled

Tags: android, material-design

I use multiple of the new TextInputLayout & TextInputEditText objects in my Android project, as described here: https://material.io/develop/android/components/text-input-layout/

But, no matter what I do, I cannot get the field to appear 'grey' when it is disabled. In fact, it looks the same either way.

Here is how I define it in my Layout:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/username_wrapper"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header_container"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/list_verticle_margin"
            android:hint="@string/username">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/username_field"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I also had to overwrite a color in my colors.xml file:

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#fff</color>
```

Although, removing this does not make much of a difference. 
Can anyone please help me figure out how to make this appear disabled?

Here is the resulting textfield: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: ok, well for now it seems that: instead of disabling the edittext, one needs to disable the layout part. Also, you need to overwrite mtrl_textinput_disabled_color in your colors.xml. So i guess I'm going with that for now. (https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/112)

Comment: Having the same issue, looks like its broken.

Answer (score 3):

I forgot I asked this question...

Here is how I solved it (but it affects ALL the TextInputs).

1. Overwrite the disabled color in your colors.xml file:

`<color name="mtrl_textinput_disabled_color" tools:override="true">#919191</color>`

2. Set the TextInputLayout and the TextInputEditText as disabled from the code. Hope this helps someone!!

UPDATE: YOU NO LONGER HAVE TO OVERWRITE 'mtrl_textinput_disabled_color'.
With new material components, you can just set a style like:

```
<style name="example.TextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/example_color</item>
    //// Other stuff here if you want.
</style>
```

example_color.xml in your colors directory, looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:color="@color/textDefault"/>
</selector>
```

Then you can apply the style to any InputTextLayout, using

```
style="@style/example.TextInputLayout"
```

in its xml. This gives a lot more flexibility and allows you to be able to style each TextInputLayout individually if you so wished.

Comment: Very nice. However, do you know what's the issue with setting the disabled state from the XML, it doesn´t seem to work at all.

Comment: Sorry, not a clue. I'm still a bit of a noob myself.